# why page_load still fired after preinit jumps to another page

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have a aspx page which checkes whether user is logged in inside preinit. If not, the page will jump to another page. However, the code inside page_load is still fired even if the page jumps. Is this right? If I don't want to run code inside page_load, what should I do?

regards,
alex

Comment: Page load always runs. Use `Request.IsAuthenticated` in Page_Load to check if the user is logged in and apply redirect.

Answer (score 1):

Response.Redirect jumps from the browser client.

You can pass a endResponse param with true to end the current page.

```
Response.Redirect(url, true);
```

Or：

```
Response.Redirect(url);
Response.End();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use an if-else. If the user is not logged, jump to the page, else - execute your code.